# What can be used for automating webservices instead of selenium-wire?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework, seleniumwire

I am trying to automate web services (underlying requests made by the browser) behind the specific web page.First capture network traffic and then logging just some of specific urls in the log file. Do you have any idea regarding tools, drivers?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you get to the access log of the server? Or do you want to automate using other peoples' services through their regular web API?

Comment: I want to track specific web service urls behind the web page. Tracking for related urls are awake or not. Can i use browsermob proxy or any other drivers, tools instead of selenium-wire? How can i collect driver.requests? Do you have any other preferences?

Comment: I approach problems like that from the backend side, because that's where I work. If that is not possible for you, you need answers from other people.